# MVC and dynamic titles

Tags: php, model-view-controller, seo

What's the best way to go about having dynamic titles when your site uses the MVC pattern?

I've seen some frameworks set the title in the controller with something like `$seo->setTitle('Title here...')` but that is no good when you want dynamic titles like on a products page you would want the products name in the title.

I was thinking of having an SEO object, create it in the controller and in the constructor have the page name and by using the provided page name the methods within the object retrieve and set the pageTitle and desciption properties.

Would it be considered to be bad practice or breaking some rule of MVC? and if yes, what is a better approach? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generation of page titles is part of *presentation logic*, thus it should be handled in View part of MVC design pattern.

Keep in mind, that a proper `View` is not a dumb `Template`. Instead views should be responsible for all the presentation logic in your application and able to juggle multiple templates.

The rest depend on which MVC-inspired pattern you try to apply. In the Model2 MVC and HMVC patterns view is active, and able to request information from model layer. If you implement MVP or MVVM, they contain a passive view, which gets information from controllers.

Comment: So in my head.php view file have a function like getTitle($pageNameHere) that will return the needed page title for that page? In my MVC the view files can access the model.

Comment: Yes, it would make sense for `View` instance to have such method. But the `'head.php'` sounds more like a template to me.

Comment: Ok thanks and what do you mean it sounds more like a template? In my views folder I have a /common folder and in that I have head.php, header.php and footer.php. They are included when the $view->render() method is run. Is there something wrong?

Comment: Compare your current "view" with this code here: http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html

Comment: After reading that article I see that he sets the page title in the controller, is that not breaking the rule that presentation logic should be in the `View`?

Comment: The point was to show you, that what you call "view" is actually a "template".

Answer (score 2):

I do not see what is wrong with doing

```
$seo->setTitle($productName . " page title....");
```

The $productName variable could be used easily.